# Calculating Percentage of Tax Revenue

Tags: economics

So the question asks me to find the % tax revenue but I can't seem to get the right answer, can anyone help?

The demand and supply functions for pens with a tax imposed on the buyers is given by:

$Q^D = 92 – 4 (Ps + T)$

$Q^S = -168 +12 (Ps)$

$Q = Q^D = Q^S$

The price to the buyer was initially \$16 and \$1 tax. However, the government decided to raise the tax to \$2.00 for this amount. This caused a drop in the quantity sold from the initial $Q=24.$

Assume $T = \$2$

Comment: % tax revenue with respect to what?

Answer (score 0):

Demand function 
$$
P^D(Q,T)=23-\frac{Q}{4}-T=P^D(Q,0)-T
$$
Supply function
$$
P^S(Q)=14+\frac{Q}{12}
$$
For $T=T_0=0$, the equilibrium is at $(Q_0,P_0)=(27,65/4)$.

For $T=T_1=1$, we have the equilibrium quantity $Q_1=24$ and the tax revenue 
$$
R_1=\big[P^D(Q_1,T_0)-P^D(Q_1,T_1)\big]\times Q_1=T_1\times Q_1=24
$$
For $T=T_2=2$, we have the equilibrium quantity $Q_2=21$ and the tax revenue 
$$
R_2=\big[P^D(Q_2,T_0)-P^D(Q_2,T_2)\big]\times Q_2=T_2\times Q_2=42
$$
with an increase of $\Delta R=R_2-R_1=18$, that is an increase of $\frac{\Delta R}{R_1}=75\%$.